# Execute with 'make run'

Tags: makefile

Say I have a makefile, upon compiling with the command make, it produces an executable named 'run'.

So far, I know that 'make' is used to compile multiple source codes but what I have never heard of is you can use 'make' to execute the executable.

Is it possible to execute the binary with this command later with 'make run'?

I think this one is basic question but I'm yet to find an answer.

Sorry if it hurts some of the people here. =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [`.PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) target called run.

```
.PHONY: run
run:
        ./executableName
```

`.PHONY` means that the makefile won't create a file and will run the command every time.

Note: Most likely you have a target that is to make the executable. Do not give the `.PHONY` target the same name as the executable.

Comment: Thanks and I should have made more searches before asking.
Good day!

Comment: Just another question perhaps. 
When I run, 'make run', is it possible to get rid of "./executableName" from appearing in the console?

Comment: @afiqjohari To hide the command from being show you can add an `@` to the front of the command. So you can change `./executableName` to `@./executableName`

Answer (score 0):

No, to run the program type

```
./run
```

Comment: That's the thing. My professor asks to compile with make and he said he will then execute the program with 'make run'

So it supposes 'make' to be able to execute the program in some ways..